# PayPal Checkout JS SDK onError not triggering when cards not processed

Tags: paypal

I am trying to redirect customers to an error page for my website if their card cannot be processed. It not working and all I can get is the standard PayPal alert that says "Things don't appear to be working at the moment."

What confuses me especially is that I have a redirect page for purchase approval that IS working correctly in the onApprove function (seen below).

PayPal JavaScript SDK says this is the code to redirect customers to a customer URL:

```
paypal.Buttons({
  onError: function (err) {
    // For example, redirect to a specific error page
    window.location.href = "/your-error-page-here";
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

This is what my onError function looks like:

```
onError: function (err) {
        //My Redirect Page
        window.location.href = "https://www.fitnessbydylan.com/error-page.html";
}
```

This is my full Javascript for my PayPal button.

```
             <script>
                    function initPayPalButton() {
                      paypal.Buttons({
                        style: {
                          shape: 'rect',
                          color: 'gold',
                          layout: 'vertical',
                          label: 'paypal',
                          
                        },

                        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                          return actions.order.create({
                            purchase_units: [{"description":"1 MONTH DIGITAL COACHING","amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":0.06,"breakdown":{"item_total":{"currency_code":"USD","value":0.06},"shipping":{"currency_code":"USD","value":0},"tax_total":{"currency_code":"USD","value":0.00}}}}]
                          });
                        },

                        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                           // Simulate a mouse click:
                           window.location.href = "http://www.fitnessbydylan.com/purchase-page.html";
                           alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                          });
                        },

                        onError: function (err) {
                          // My Redirect Page
                          window.location.href = "https://www.fitnessbydylan.com/error-page.html";
                        },
                        
                      }).render('#paypal-button-container'); 
                    }
                    initPayPalButton();
             </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onError` is only triggered when there is a technical problem with loading or using the buttons, which is a very rare situation. It is not triggered for card processing problems.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense.